# Problems with Cache Control Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

How I change the cache-control to have the same properties of x-magento-cache-control on response Header?

Above my inspect:

**cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store** *(I Need change this)*

**x-magento-cache-control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400**

Anyone can help-me?

Comment: welcome, have you tried adding this to the header of the theme <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=86400" />

Comment: Hi There, where I put this code? Can you explain to me?

Comment: You should be to add this to the Magento_Theme/templates/html/head.phtml file which should give you the result your after all depending on if you have that as part of your theme